# Is there simple proof that no finite polynomial with rational coefficients can generate only primes?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

There are many proofs, suitable for beginners and new students, that there is no polynomial that generates only primes - with the constraint that the polynomial has finite terms, is non-constant, and has positive **integer** coefficients.

However, searching the internet and this maths stack exchange - there does not appear to be a simple proof that loosens the requirements to positive **rational** coefficients.

The question has been discussed in comments to other questions, but no proof set out, or linked to.

I would appreciate a short simple proof, suitable for beginners (not trained at university maths).

Also can the proofs be extended to **negative** coefficients, integer or rational?

Comment: The proof for polynomials also works when coefficients are allowed to be negative integers. For rational polynomias $P$, with integer $P(0)$, see that $P(nX)$ has integer coefficients, where $n$ is the lcm of the denominators of the coefficients. Not sure of the general case though, although we know they can be written as linear combinations with integer coefficients of the $\binom{X}{k}$.

Comment: Specific to negative coefficients, note that applying a shift to $x$ in $p(x)$ such as $x=y+q$ causes an adjustment in the signs of coefficients; with large enough $q$, all coefficients will match the sign of the leading coefficient.

Comment: @tonimhax: this idea works out correctly when using the binomial form of polynomials as $p(x)=a\binom xn+b\binom x{n-1}+\dots$

Comment: Let me put previous comments another way: you may want to look at contrapositive, i.e. if there exists prime-only generating polynomial with rational coefficients, you can prove that there should exists prime-only generating polynomial with integer coefficients by considering $P(nx)$, where $n$ is least common multiple of denominators. For positive-negative coefficients consider $P(x^2)$

Answer (score 1):

A proof very easy was given by the great Alan Baker for all polynomial $f(x)$ with integer coefficients:
$$f(mf(n)+n)\text{ is divisible by $f(n)$ for all integer $m$ }.$$

Comment: You must mean $f(m f(n) + n)$. This is of course instant from reduction modulo $f(n)$.

Comment: Right. Thank you.

Comment: This can also be seen by the Taylor expansion $f(mf(n)+n)=f(n)+mf(n)f'(n)+m^2f(n)^2\frac{f''(n)}{2} + \cdots$.

Comment: @Merosity I think Taylor expansion is a bit of a red herring. How do you justify that $f''(n)/2 \in \mathbb{Z}$? You'd really need to write $f(x+n) = \sum a_k x^k$ where $a_k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and set $x=m f(n)$. The derivatives are just picking off the $a_k$ coefficients.

Comment: Since $f(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients, it's a linear combination of   monomials. $\frac{1}{k!}\frac{d^k}{dx^k}x^n = \binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}$ is just shifting the exponent and multiplying by an integer, so it's still a polynomial with integer coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Let the polynomial be
$f(x) = a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...+a_nx^n$ where $a_i$ is rational for  $0 \le i \le n$
$a_i = \frac{p_i}{q_1}$ where $p_i,q_i$ are coprime
Assume $f(x)$ always produces primes.
Let $f(k)$ be integer for some $k$. Therefore $f(k)$ is prime.Let $f(k) = q$ where $q$ is prime.
$f(k) \equiv 0\pmod q$
$f(k+nq)\equiv 0\pmod q$. Here $f(k+nq)$ is an integer and n is any natural numer divisible by the LCM of all the $q_i$ for $0 \le i \le n$.
Since $f(n+kq)$ is prime, it has to be $q$.
But $f(x)$ is an increasing function(if it nonconstant)
So $f(k+nq)>f(k)$
but $f(k+nq)=f(k)=q$
There is a contradiction.
You can create a very simillar proof even if the coefficients are negative.
Hope this helps